# How can I create a more generic Resolver for Automapper?

Tags: automapper

For certain properties, when the value is 0, I want to convert the value to NULL.

When I create my map I use a custom resolver to handle the conversion for me, which looks like:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<ContactData, Contact>()
     .ForMember(x => x.ContactTypeId, y => y.ResolveUsing<ContactTypeIdZeroToNullResolver>());
```

And my resolver looks like:

```
using AutoMapper;

namespace MyCompany.MyProduct.Customers.Data.Helpers
{
    public class ContactTypeIdZeroToNullResolver : ValueResolver<ContactData, int?>
    {
        protected override int? ResolveCore(ContactData source)
        {
            if (source.ContactTypeId == 0)
                return null;

            return source.ContactTypeId;
        }
    }
}
```

This works just fine!

My question is, is it possible to make this more generic? I tried replace ContactData with just int, but errors keep being thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```cs
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<int, int?>()
    .ConvertUsing(src => src == 0 ? (int?)null : src);

AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<ContactData, Contact>();

AutoMapper.Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

(assuming of course that `ContactTypeId` is an `int` in `ContactData` and an `int?` in `Contact`)

You should be careful with this as it will apply to ALL your mappings for these types.

You can also inline it like this:

```cs
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<ContactData, Contact>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ContactTypeId,
                       opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ContactTypeId == 0
                            ? (int?)null
                            : src.ContactTypeId));
```

which will achieve the same thing, but wont be as generic.